# Posterior predictive: what happens to integral over parameters?

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference

#### Question

I don't understand how when integrating over the parameters in the posterior predictive, the integration "disappears". It's hard for me to ask simply because I am confused, so here is an example.

#### Example

Imagine we have a Gaussian model with unknown mean $\mu$ and fixed variance $\sigma^2$. If $D$ is the training data and $D'$ is unseen data, then the posterior predictive is

$$
\begin{align}
p(D' \mid D)
&= \int p(D' \mid D, \mu) p(\mu \mid D) d\mu
\\
&\stackrel{\star}{=} \int p(D' \mid \mu) p(\mu \mid D) d\mu
\\
&\triangleq \int \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu, \sigma^2) \mathcal{N}(\mu \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2) d \mu
\end{align}
$$

where step $\star$ holds because the modeling assumption is that $D'$ is conditionally independent from $D$ given $\mu$ and the definitions of $\mu_N$ and $\sigma_N^2$ fall out of computing the posterior. See Bishop (2006) page 98 for details.

Here is where I am confused. I can show that

$$
\mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu, \sigma^2) \mathcal{N}(\mu \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2) = \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2 + \sigma^2)
$$

Murphy's derivation in [Conjugate Bayesian analysis of the Gaussian distribution](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf) suggests looking at Bishop, equation 2.115 (see my edit for more). My trouble is, Murphy then claims that

$$
p(D \mid D') = \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2 + \sigma^2)
$$

which is what I mean by the integration should "disappearing". What happened? I understand that this new distribution has no dependence on $\mu$, but I would have expected

$$
\begin{align}
p(D' \mid D)
&= \int \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu, \sigma^2) \mathcal{N}(\mu \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2) d \mu
\\
&= \int \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2 + \sigma^2) d \mu
\\
&= \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2 + \sigma^2) \int d \mu
\end{align}
$$

But it's unclear what becomes of the integral. It's not a probability, so it's not like this is guaranteed to be 1.

---

#### Edit

This is my derivation based on Murphy's hint to look at Bishop (2006), page 93. Since both our posterior and prior are Gaussians, we can use the following fact:

$$
\begin{align}
p(\textbf{x}) &= \mathcal{N}(\textbf{x} \mid \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Psi})
\\
p(\textbf{y} \mid \textbf{x}) &= \mathcal{N}(\textbf{y} \mid A \textbf{x} + \textbf{b}, \textbf{P})
\\
&\Downarrow
\\
p(\textbf{y}) &= \mathcal{N}(\textbf{y} \mid \textbf{A} \boldsymbol{\mu} + \textbf{b}, \textbf{P} + \textbf{A} \boldsymbol{\Psi} \textbf{A}^{\top})
\end{align}
$$

where we have

$$
\begin{align}
\textbf{x} &= \mu \\
\boldsymbol{\mu} &= \mu_N \\
\boldsymbol{\Psi} &= \sigma_N^2 \\
\textbf{y} &= D' \\
\textbf{A} &= 1 \\
\textbf{b} &= 0 \\
\textbf{P} &= \sigma^2
\end{align}
$$

This gives us

$$
\begin{align}
p(\mu) &= \mathcal{N}(\mu \mid \mu_N, \mu_N^2)
\\
p(D' \mid \mu) &= \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu, \sigma^2)
\\
p(D' \mid \mu) p(\mu) = p(D') &= \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma^2 + \sigma_N^2)
\end{align}
$$

We can add conditioning on $D$ at every step if we'd like, since it doesn't effect the distributions provided we have the parameters (i.i.d.):

$$
\begin{align}
p(\mu \mid D) &= \mathcal{N}(\mu \mid \mu_N, \mu_N^2)
\\
p(D' \mid \mu, D) &= \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu, \sigma^2)
\\
p(D' \mid \mu, D) p(\mu) = p(D' \mid D) &= \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma^2 + \sigma_N^2)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How did you manage to show that $
\mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu, \sigma^2) \mathcal{N}(\mu \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2) = \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2 + \sigma^2)
$ without integrating out $\mu$, after which the integral has disappeared?

Comment: As far as I can tell, $p(D^\prime\mid D)$ isn't a probability, either: it's a probability *density* and therefore can have any nonnegative value--and even be infinite.

Comment: @jbowman, I've added the derivation I used based on Murphy's hint to look at Bishop, equation 2.115.

Comment: The line after "I would have expected" doesn't make sense; you are integrating with respect to $u$, but there is no $u$ in the formula being integrated.  Do you mean to integrate wrt $\mu$?  If so, note that $
\mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu, \sigma^2) \mathcal{N}(\mu \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2) = \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2 + \sigma^2)
$ is not true; what *is* true is that $
\int_{\mu} \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu, \sigma^2) \mathcal{N}(\mu \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2)d\mu = \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2 + \sigma^2)
$, so your next derivation won't have a $du$ in it if you do it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I meant w.r.t $\mu$ (so $d \mu$) and have fixed that typo. I appreciate your comment, but my entire question is why your comment holds. Another way of asking my question is: what is wrong with my derivation in my edit? In my edit, I show my logic for why $\mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu, \sigma^2) \mathcal{N}(\mu \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2) = \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2 + \sigma^2)$. I understand that this must be wrong (or is inconsistent with Murphy). I don't understand why it is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly the question, it seems to me (and others before me in the comment section) that the derivation
$$\mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu, \sigma^2) \mathcal{N}(\mu \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2) = \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N^2 + \sigma^2)$$
or equivalently
$$p(D' \mid \mu, D) p(\mu) = p(D' \mid D) = \mathcal{N}(D' \mid \mu_N, \sigma^2 + \sigma_N^2)$$
is incorrect since the left hand side is a *joint* density on $(D',\mu)$ and the right hand side is a *marginal* density on $D'$. (When removing $\mu$ from the above rhs, it is as if $\mu$ is already integrated, but I advise against such loose reasonging.)

What is correct is that, if
$$\underbrace{D'|\mu\sim}_\text{conditional}\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\underbrace{\mu\sim}_\text{marginal}\mathcal{N}(\mu_N, \sigma_N^2)$$then
$$\underbrace{D'\sim}_\text{marginal}\mathcal{N}(\mu_N, \sigma^2+\sigma_N^2)$$
as stated in [the book](https://amzn.to/2X6cR5z).

Comment: I see. I used Bishop's 2.115 incorrectly. It is not that $p(y) = p(y \mid x)p(x)$, which is obviously wrong now that I write it out explicitly. It is $p(y) = \int p(y \mid x)p(x) dx$.